# Express server public stylesheet not being fetched/applied

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm learning how to serve pages with node, express and ejs. I am trying to link a stylesheet to index.ejs by using a public folder but when I visit the page in my browser there are no styles, and the network tab doesn't show a request for the stylesheet. When I go to localhost:3000/styles.css, the file shows up no problem. The files look like this:

index.ejs

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sam's Site | <%= title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/styles.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {title: 'Home');
});
```

app.js is in the top level folder, index.ejs is in a views folder, and styles.css is in a public folder. When I inspect it in the browser, the header shows up normally and the link tag looks like it should be working.

I've tried changing the source to several different variations of the path to styles.css and I've made sure styles contains valid css. Can anyone explain why the stylesheet is not being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

instead of : `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

You are using public folder as default in express. So, no need to specify the path.

Comment: This is actually what I had before but changed it to try and fix the problem. Thanks for letting me know though.

Answer (score 0):

Your link tag should have an `href` attribute instead of `src`.